# Регулярное выражение выборки конкретных значений

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

Мужики и девушки, выручайте, нужно срочно, поэтому сейчас не могу сильно углубиться в познания регулярок.

Нужно в Linux'е прочесть весь файл и в кажой строке оставить только конкретные значения, Например:

есть файл file.txt, c содержимым:

```
../logs/example.ru-err_log:[22-Jan-2013 11:51:49] Success! Coldmade Game. INFO. (gorkii). scat=[ 1 ]../logs/example.ru-err_log:[23-Jan-2013 11:39:19] Success! Coldmade Game. INFO. (gorkii). scat=[ 2 ]../logs/example.ru-err_log:[30-Jan-2013 15:13:18] Success! Coldmade Game. INFO. (Moorphy). scat=[ 2 ]../logs/example.ru-err_log:[30-Jan-2013 15:13:24] Success! Coldmade Game. INFO. (killer_sto). scat=[ 1 ]../logs/example.ru-err_log:[30-Jan-2013 15:13:35] Success! Coldmade Game. INFO. (goldenAxe). scat=[ 4 ]
```

В итоге нужно получить что-то типо:

```
22-Jan-2013 11:51:49,gorkii22-Jan-2013 11:39:19,gorkii30-Jan-2013 15:13:18,Moorphy30-Jan-2013 15:13:24,killer_sto30-Jan-2013 15:13:35,goldenAxe
```

В общем, нужно выбрать только даты и логины пользователей. В идеале, конечно же, нужно исключить логины, если на этот день уже есть действие INFO (то есть, если в тот же день такой же логи уже присутствует).

Надеюсь все понятно. Если что, на связи, жду ответов )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По быстрому так набросал:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/.*:\[\(.*\)\] Success.* \(\(.*\)\)\. scat.*/\1 \2/'|sed 's/ (/,/g' | sed 's/)//g'
```

Результат

```
22-Jan-2013 11:51:49,gorkii23-Jan-2013 11:39:19,gorkii30-Jan-2013 15:13:18,Moorphy30-Jan-2013 15:13:24,killer_sto30-Jan-2013 15:13:35,goldenAxe
```

Насчет исключить логины;

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/.*:\[\(.*\)\] Success.* \(\(.*\)\)\. scat.*/\1 \2/'|sed 's/ (/ /g' | sed 's/)//g'  | cut -f 1,3 -d " " | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Например, в результате будет: На 22 января логин gorkii будет присутствовать два раз, как исключить повторение на каждый день?

Comment: Нужно выбрать пользователей, которые совершали какие-либо действия раз в день (уникальные записи).